# Fastest way to determine whether elements of a vector y occur in a vector x

Tags: c++

I have the following problem: I have two vectors `x` and `y` of type double that are increasingly sorted and I would like to obtain a vector `z` indicating whether an element of `y` is present in `x`. Up to now, I have used `std::binary_search` in a for-loop as illustrated below, but I think there should be a faster way making use of the fact that also `x` is sorted?
The issue is that this needs to be super fast as it turns out to be the bottleneck in my code.

For those familiar with R, I need an equivalent to `match(y, x, nomatch = 0L) > 0L`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

int main() {

    using namespace std;

    vector<double> x = {1.8, 2.4, 3.3, 4.2, 5.6,7.9, 8.5, 9.3};
    vector<double> y = {0.5, 0.98, 1.8, 3.1, 5.6, 6.6, 9.3, 9.3, 9.5};

    vector<bool> z(y.size());
    for (int i = 0; i != y.size(); ++i)
        z[i] = binary_search(x.begin(), x.end(), y[i]);

    for (vector<bool>::const_iterator i = z.begin(); i != z.end(); ++i)
        cout << *i << " ";

    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**

Here are representative sample data for my problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

// function generator:
double RandomNumber () { return (std::rand() / 10e+7); }

int main() {

    using namespace std;
    std::srand ( unsigned ( std::time(0) ) );

    // 5000 is representative
    int n = 5000;

    std::vector<double> x (n);
    std::generate (x.begin(), x.end(), RandomNumber);

    std::vector<double> y (n);
    std::generate (y.begin(), y.end(), RandomNumber);

    for(std::vector<double>::const_iterator i = x.begin(); i != x.end(); i++) {
    y.push_back(*i);
}

    std::sort(x.begin(), x.end());
    std::sort(y.begin(), y.end());

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `binary_search` does assume a sorted range.

Comment: But keep in mind that because you are using double if those tables are being filled from different calculations/sources you might not find the exact match.

Comment: @concept3d I'm aware of this, but since I do not know better I blindly trusted that the numerical comparison of `binary_search` uses a reasonable tolerance.

Comment: AFAIK it doesn't. I think you need pass your overloaded version of the comparison function.

Comment: The best answer depends on the relative size of your relative vectors. IF they're both equally large `std::set_itersection` is the best solution, if not a binary search approach will be faster. You'll have to provide a reasonable benchmark sample to really get an answer.

Comment: @Voo Actually x is (on average) about half the size of y and is a subset of y. I try do add a representative example to my question.

Comment: @Dominik In that case if your vectors aren't tiny (although even then in practice it'd probably be), the `set_itersection` solution should be faster. But yes best add a representative sample to it (even better an actual benchmark suite with something like [google/benchmark](https://github.com/google/benchmark)). The way to get quality answers on questions such as these is to make it a challenge to people.

Comment: @Voo I know what you mean, but I'm just a beginner with C++ and right know seriously overwhelmed by you guys. I first need to check out what a benchmark suite actually is.

Comment: @Dominik Simplest said a program that allows you to easily time code on varying inputs to decide which function is the fastest for some particular input. The link to [google/benchmark](https://github.com/google/benchmark)  above is really your best bet in C++. It's also a good general tip: Never try to optimize something if you can't do an objective comparison.

Comment: @Dominik there in the bottom of the answers is the code to perform a benchmark between all the alternatives they have provided you. Run it on your computer and you will have your implementation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`std::set_itersection`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection):

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<double> x {1.8, 2.4, 3.3, 4.2, 5.6,7.9, 8.5, 9.3};
    std::vector<double> y {0.5, 0.98, 1.8, 3.1, 5.6, 6.6, 9.3, 9.3, 9.5};

    std::vector<double> z {};

    std::set_intersection(std::cbegin(x), std::cend(x), 
                          std::cbegin(y), std::cend(y), 
                          std::back_inserter(z));

   std::copy(std::cbegin(z), std::cend(z),
             std::ostream_iterator<double> {std::cout, " "});
}
```

**Edit**

To address Dieter Lücking point in the comments, here is a version that more closely matches R's match function:

```
#include <vector>
#include <deque>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <functional>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
std::deque<bool> match(const std::vector<T>& y, const std::vector<T>& x)
{
    std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<const T>> z {};
    z.reserve(std::min(y.size(), x.size()));

    std::set_intersection(std::cbegin(y), std::cend(y),
                          std::cbegin(x), std::cend(x),
                          std::back_inserter(z));

    std::deque<bool> result(y.size(), false);

    for (const auto& e : z) {
        result[std::distance(std::addressof(y.front()), std::addressof(e.get()))] = true;
    }

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<double> x {1.8, 2.4, 3.3, 4.2, 5.6,7.9, 8.5, 9.3};
    std::vector<double> y {0.5, 0.98, 1.8, 3.1, 5.6, 6.6, 9.3, 9.3, 9.5};

    const auto matches = match(y, x);

    std::copy(std::cbegin(matches), std::cend(matches),
              std::ostream_iterator<bool> {std::cout});
}
```

Comment: Thank your for the answer, but I initially used this approach and it seems to be much slower, as it does not take into account the information that both vectors are increasingly sorted.

Comment: @Dominik Yes it does, in fact it *requires* that both input ranges be sorted. Please post code demonstrating this approach is slower than using `std::binary_search`.

Comment: @Dominik To be more precise, `std::set_intersection` is guaranteed to make *at most* `2 * (x.size() + y.size() - 1)` comparisons in this example, where as your `std::binary_search` code is only good for `y.size() * (log2(x.size()) + O(1))`.

Comment: @Dominik Your binary search approach needs O(n*log m) while this here is required to be O(n+m). And the naive implementation which is pretty much required here should have no particular large overhead, so I'd think your benchmarks are flawed. Post the code for those.

Comment: There is another search required to find the indices of the `vector<double> z` (in this answer) to make it equivalent to the vector<bool> z` (in the question).

Answer (score 3):

I picked up all your codes, Dieter timing sample and the sample data of 5000 random doubles of the OP to perform a more complete timing of all the alternatives. This is the code:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <assert.h>
#include <deque>
#include <functional>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

double RandomNumber () { return (std::rand() / 10e+7); }

template <typename T>
std::deque<bool> match(const std::vector<T>& y, const std::vector<T>& x)
{
    std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<const T>> z {};
    z.reserve(std::min(y.size(), x.size()));

    std::set_intersection(y.cbegin(), y.cend(),
                          x.cbegin(), x.cend(),
                          std::back_inserter(z));

    std::deque<bool> result(y.size(), false);

    for (const auto& e : z) {
        result[std::distance(std::addressof(y.front()), std::addressof(e.get()))] = true;
    }

    return result;
}

int main() {

    const int NTESTS = 10;

    long long time1 = 0;
    long long time2 = 0;
    long long time3 = 0;
    long long time3_prime = 0;
    long long time4 = 0;
    long long time5 = 0;
    long long time6 = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < NTESTS; ++i){

        std::srand ( unsigned ( std::time(0) ) );

        // 5000 is representative
        int n = 5000;

        std::vector<double> x (n);
        std::generate (x.begin(), x.end(), RandomNumber);

        std::vector<double> y (n);
        std::generate (y.begin(), y.end(), RandomNumber);

        for(std::vector<double>::const_iterator i = x.begin(); i != x.end(); i++) {
            y.push_back(*i);
        }

        std::sort(x.begin(), x.end());
        std::sort(y.begin(), y.end());

        vector<bool> z1(y.size());
        vector<unsigned char> z2(y.size());
        vector<unsigned char> z3(y.size());
        std::deque<bool> z3_prime;
        vector<bool> z4(y.size());
        std::vector<bool> z5(y.size());
        std::vector<bool> z6(y.size());

        // Original
        {
            auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

            for (size_t i = 0; i != y.size(); ++i) {
                z1[i] = binary_search(x.begin(), x.end(), y[i]);
            }
            auto stop = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
            auto duration = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::nanoseconds>(stop - start);
            time1 += duration.count();
        }

        // Original (replacing vector<bool> by vector<unsigned char>)
        {
            auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

            for (size_t i = 0; i != y.size(); ++i) {
                z2[i] = binary_search(x.begin(), x.end(), y[i]);
            }
            auto stop = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
            auto duration = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::nanoseconds>(stop - start);
            time2 += duration.count();
        }

        {  // Dieter Lücking set_intersection
            auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

            size_t ix = 0;
            size_t iy = 0;
            while(ix < x.size() && iy < y.size())
            {
                if(x[ix] < y[iy]) ++ix;
                else if(y[iy] < x[ix]) ++iy;
                else {
                    z3[iy] = 1;
                    // ++ix; Not this if one vector is not uniquely sorted
                    ++iy;
                }
            }
            auto stop = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
            auto duration = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::nanoseconds>(stop - start);
            time3 += duration.count();
        }

        // Std::set_intersection
        {
            auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

            z3_prime = match(y, x);

            auto stop = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
            auto duration = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::nanoseconds>(stop - start);
            time3_prime += duration.count();
        }

        { // Ed Heal
            auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

            int i_x = 0, i_y = 0;
            while (i_x < x.size() && i_y < y.size())
            {
                if (x[i_x] == y[i_y]) {
                    //cout << "In both" << x[i_x] << endl;
                    z4[i_y] = true;
                    ++i_x;
                    ++i_y;
                } else if (x[i_x] < y[i_y]) {
                    ++i_x;
                } else {
                    z4[i_y] = false;
                    ++i_y;
                }
            }

           /* for (; i_y < y.size(); ++i_y) {
                //Empty
            } */
            auto stop = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
            auto duration = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::nanoseconds>(stop - start);
            time4 += duration.count();
        }

        { //  JacquesdeHooge
            auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
            auto it_x = x.begin();
            int i = 0;
            for (; i < (int)y.size(); ++i) {
                it_x = std::lower_bound(it_x, x.end(), y[i]);
                if (it_x == x.end()) break;
                z5[i] = *it_x == y[i];
            }
            std::fill(z5.begin() + i, z5.end(), false);
            auto stop = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
            auto duration = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::nanoseconds>(stop - start);
            time5 += duration.count();
        }

        { // Skizz
            auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
            vector<double>::iterator a = x.begin(), b = y.begin();
            int i = 0;
            while (a != x.end () && b != y.end ())
            {
                if (*a == *b) {
                    z6[i] = true;
                    ++a;
                    ++b;
                }
                else
                {
                    z6[i] = false;
                    if (*a < *b)
                    {
                        ++a;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ++b;
                    }
                }
                i++;
            }
            auto stop = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
            auto duration = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::nanoseconds>(stop - start);
            time6 += duration.count();
        }

        assert (std::equal(z1.begin(), z1.begin() + 5000, z2.begin()));
        assert (std::equal(z1.begin(), z1.begin() + 5000, z3.begin()));
        assert (std::equal(z1.begin(), z1.begin() + 5000, z3_prime.begin()));
        assert (std::equal(z1.begin(), z1.begin() + 5000, z4.begin()));
        assert (std::equal(z1.begin(), z1.begin() + 5000, z5.begin()));
        assert (std::equal(z1.begin(), z1.begin() + 5000, z6.begin()));
    }

    cout << "Original - vector<bool>: \t\t" << time1 << " ns\n";
    cout << "Original - vector<unsigned char>: \t" << time2 << " ns\n";
    cout << "Set intersection (Daniel): \t\t" << time3_prime << " ns\n";
    cout << "Set intersection (Dieter Lücking): \t" << time3 << " ns\n";
    cout << "Ed Heal: \t\t\t\t" << time4 << " ns\n";
    cout << "JackesdeHooge: \t\t\t\t" << time5 << " ns\n";
    cout << "Skizz: \t\t\t\t\t" << time6 << " ns\n";
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**My results** with g++ 5.2.1 -std::c++11 and -O3:

Original - vector:        10152069 ns

Original - vector:   8686619 ns

Set intersection (Daniel):      1768855 ns

Set intersection (Dieter Lücking):  1617106 ns

Ed Heal:                1446596 ns

JackesdeHooge:              3998958 ns

Skizz:                  1385193 ns

*Please note Ed Heal and Skizz solutions are essentially the same.

Comment: Thank you Frank, this is really helpful and gives me some guidelines. Maybe you could alter 'set intersection' to  'Dieter', as it is not using `std::set_intersection`.

Comment: Would you mind to add the "real" `set_intersection` of Daniel to the benchmarks? I just tested it on my machine an it seems to be 5 times slower than Dieter's solution.

Comment: Updated. I had to adapt Daniel code to compile it with c++11. Hope it helps.

Comment: Very much appreciated. It seems that something went wrong for me with Daniel's code.

Answer (score 2):

Since both vectors are sorted, you have to apply bin search only on the remainder part of the second vector.

So if you e.g. don't find x [i] in before y [j], you're certain you also won't find x [i + 1] before y [j]. In finding a match for x [i + 1] it therefore suffices to apply bin search starting with y [j].

Comment: Thank you, I figured this out, too, but I don't know how to program it and was wondering if there is some function doing exactly this.

Comment: There's no need for binary search at all, every step in the loop you increase the iterator that points to the smaller object. If both are equivalent at some point insert that element into the result vector. But then that's what std::set_itersection is doing and that's optimal.

Comment: @Voo: Bin search can be useful. This can be seen from the extreme case where x has only one element.

Comment: @Jacques You're right I ignored uneven distributions. It's O(n log m) vs. O(n + m). So if n is smaller than m/log(m) that method is better. The constant overhead is probably similar, although binary search isn't particularly great for caches.

Answer (score 2):

Off the top of my head, I can only think of this:-

```
vector<double>::iterator a = x.begin(), b = y.begin();

while (a != x.end () && b != y.end ())
{
  if (*a == *b)
  {
     // value is in both containers
     ++a;
  }
  else
  {
    if (*a < *b)
    {
      ++a;
    }
    else
    {
      ++b;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Should you increment both when they are in the same vector?

Comment: @EdHeal: Yeah, I was wondering about that, it depends on how you treat lists with duplicate values.

Comment: That's a form of linear search. If the number of elements in x is much smaller then the number of elements in y, that would be needlessly slow.

Comment: In the worst case it would be certainly be linear, but the algorithm does terminate when the value at the end of one list is less than the current value in the other list, so it does terminate early. Would replacing the increments with a binary search be quicker? It would certainly be more complex.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this algorithm will be better as the two vectors are sorted. The time complexity is linear.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

int main() {

    using namespace std;

    vector<double> x = {1.8, 2.4, 3.3, 4.2, 5.6,7.9, 8.5, 9.3};
    vector<double> y = {0.5, 0.98, 1.8, 3.1, 5.6, 6.6, 9.3, 9.3, 9.5};

    vector<bool> z(y.size());
    int i_x = 0, i_y = 0;
    while (i_x < x.size() && i_y < y.size())
    {
        if (x[i_x] == y[i_y]) {
            cout << "In both" << x[i_x] << endl;
            z[i_y] = true;
            ++i_x;
            ++i_y;
        } else if (x[i_x] < y[i_y]) {
            ++i_x;
        } else {
            z[i_y] = false;
            ++i_y;
        }
    }

    for (; i_y < y.size(); ++i_y) {
        //Empty
    }    
    for (vector<bool>::const_iterator i = z.begin(); i != z.end(); ++i)
        cout << *i << " ";

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An implementation of @JacquesdeHooge's answer:

```
std::vector<bool> ComputeMatchFlags(const std::vector<double>& x,
                                    const std::vector<double>& y) {
  std::vector<bool> found(y.size());
  auto it_x = x.begin();
  int i = 0;
  for (; i < (int)y.size(); ++i) {
    it_x = std::lower_bound(it_x, x.end(), y[i]);
    if (it_x == x.end()) break;
    found[i] = *it_x == y[i];
  }
  std::fill(found.begin() + i, found.end(), false);
  return found;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you have found an element (or a place in the array the element would have been), you don't need to consider elements that occur before that any more. So use the result of the previous find instead of `x.begin()`.

Since `std::binary_search` does not return an iterator, use `std::lower_bound` instead. Also consider `std::find` (yes linear search, it might be actually faster, depending on your data).

If this doesn't bring enough improvement, try `std::unordered_set` instead of an array.

Answer (score 1):

Just a timing of binary search and set intersection with the improvement of using std::vector:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    using namespace std;

    // Original
    {
        vector<double> x = {1.8, 2.4, 3.3, 4.2, 5.6,7.9, 8.5, 9.3};
        vector<double> y = {0.5, 0.98, 1.8, 3.1, 5.6, 6.6, 9.3, 9.3, 9.5};

        auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        vector<bool> z(y.size());
        for (size_t i = 0; i != y.size(); ++i)
            z[i] = binary_search(x.begin(), x.end(), y[i]);
        auto stop = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        auto duration = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::nanoseconds>(stop - start);
        cout << "vector<bool>: " << duration.count() << "ns\n";
        for (auto i = z.begin(); i != z.end(); ++i)
            cout << unsigned(*i) << " ";
        cout << '\n';
    }

    // Original (replacing vector<bool> by vector<unsigned char>)
    {
        vector<double> x = {1.8, 2.4, 3.3, 4.2, 5.6,7.9, 8.5, 9.3};
        vector<double> y = {0.5, 0.98, 1.8, 3.1, 5.6, 6.6, 9.3, 9.3, 9.5};

        auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        vector<unsigned char> z(y.size());
        for (size_t i = 0; i != y.size(); ++i)
            z[i] = binary_search(x.begin(), x.end(), y[i]);
        auto stop = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        auto duration = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::nanoseconds>(stop - start);
        cout << "vector<unsigned char>: " << duration.count() << "ns\n";
        for (auto i = z.begin(); i != z.end(); ++i)
            cout << unsigned(*i) << " ";
        cout << '\n';
    }

    // Similar to std::set_intersection
    {
        vector<double> x = {1.8, 2.4, 3.3, 4.2, 5.6,7.9, 8.5, 9.3};
        vector<double> y = {0.5, 0.98, 1.8, 3.1, 5.6, 6.6, 9.3, 9.3, 9.5};

        auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        vector<unsigned char> z(y.size());
        size_t ix = 0;
        size_t iy = 0;
        while(ix < x.size() && iy < y.size())
        {
            if(x[ix] < y[iy]) ++ix;
            else if(y[iy] < x[ix]) ++iy;
            else {
                z[iy] = 1;
                // ++ix; Not this if one vector is not uniquely sorted
                ++iy;
            }
        }
        auto stop = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        auto duration = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::nanoseconds>(stop - start);
        cout << "set intersection: " << duration.count() << "ns\n";
        for (auto i = z.begin(); i != z.end(); ++i)
            cout << unsigned(*i) << " ";
        cout << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled with g++ -std=c++11 -O3 (g++ 4.84) gives:

```
vector<bool>: 3622ns
0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 
vector<unsigned char>: 1635ns
0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 
set intersection: 1299ns
0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0
```

Comment: Thank you Dieter, I just wanted to do this myself, but I am a beginner and much too slow to keep up with the speed of the discussion here.

Comment: You need to fill up the remainder of `z` in some cases